# Filesystemwatcher is not watching subdir

Tags: c#, docker, filesystemwatcher

I am trying to monitor all files created/deleted/renamed in a folder using FileSystemWatcher in a docker volume.  It is picking up events on the root dir (most of the time) that is being watched but nothing in subdir triggers an event even though IncludeSubdirectories = true. The watcher is saved as a prop. How can I get it to watch the subdir and trigger on all events not just most?

```
    public void StartMonitorService()
    {
        Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"/var/lib/docker/volumes/monitor");
        Watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes
                             | NotifyFilters.CreationTime
                             | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
                             | NotifyFilters.FileName
                             | NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                             | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                             | NotifyFilters.Security
                             | NotifyFilters.Size;

        Watcher.Created += OnCreated;
        Watcher.Deleted += OnDeleted;
        Watcher.Renamed += OnRenamed;

        Watcher.Filter = "";
        Watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't quite solve my question, but I have a work around for anyone who might have had the same issue I did.

```
private void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(e.FullPath))
    {
        string dirRoot = e.FullPath;
        DateTime lastTimeWriten = Directory.GetLastWriteTime(dirRoot);
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(30000);
            if (lastTimeWriten == Directory.GetLastWriteTime(dirRoot))
                break;

            lastTimeWriten = Directory.GetLastWriteTime(dirRoot);
        }
        HashSet<string> fileSet = new HashSet<string>(Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(dirRoot, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
        ...
        _messageService.SendNewSurveyMessage(newSurveyFileSet);
    }
}
```